# c++ dynamic array Floating Point exception

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, floating-point-exceptions

For my homework I had to design an arraylist in c++ using only 1d arrays and pointers to make the array dynamic. I have done ample testing and my functions work correctly, but when I use the main that the teacher has provided me I get this floating point error. The point of this homework is to create a class that will work for the teachers main without changing any code in the main

here is the main:

```
#include "ArrayList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    ArrayList arr;

    for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << "Should contain numbers 1..50, is ";

    cout << arr.toString() << endl;

    for (int i=arr.size()-1;i>=1;i--)
    {
        arr.erase(arr[i]);
    }   

    cout << "Should contain only 1, is ";
    cout << arr.toString() << endl;

    arr.erase(arr[0]);

    for (int i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        if (i<=2)
            arr.push_back(i);
        else
        {
            int j=1;
            while ((j<arr.size()) && (i%arr[j]!=0))
                j++;

            if (j==arr.size())
            {
                arr.push_back(i);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Prime numbers between 1 and 50 are: " << arr.toString() << endl;

}
```

here is my cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include "ArrayList.h"

using namespace std;
void ArrayList:: intialArr(int arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
}

string ArrayList:: toString()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>0 || arr[i] <0)
        {
            ss << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}

ArrayList::ArrayList()
{
    length = 1;
    capacity=0;
    arr = new int[length];
    intialArr(arr);
}

int& ArrayList:: operator[] (unsigned int i)
{
    return arr[i];
}

void ArrayList:: push_back(int m)
{
    if(capacity>=length)
    {   
       int oldlength = length;

       length = length*2;
       int* curArr = new int[length];
       intialArr(curArr);
       for (int i = 0; i < oldlength; i++)
       {
          curArr[i] = arr[i];
       }
       delete [] arr;
       arr = curArr;
    }

    arr[capacity] = m;
    capacity++;
}   


void ArrayList:: erase(int m)
{
        if(capacity == length/2)
        {   
            length = length/2;
            int* curArr = new int[length];
            intialArr(curArr);      
        for (int i = 0; i<capacity; i++)
        {
                curArr[i] = arr[i];

        }
        delete [] arr;
        arr = curArr;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==m)
            {
                for(int j = i; j<length; j++)
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                }
                capacity--;
                break;
            }
    }
    cout << "length = " << length << " capacity = " << capacity << " capacity/length = " << capacity*2 << endl;
}
```

from what I have read online floating point exceptions are normally thrown when you try to divide by zero or an infinate value arises but I dont understand how I am getting either of these issues to arise.

My code get through the main where number 1-50 are added and deleted but I get the error once I go into setting up the array to hold prime numbers (after the arr.erase(arr[0]) in the main)

I just set a couple of tags in the main to find what my number look like going into the `while ((j<arr.size()) && (i%arr[j]!=0))`and i find that my numbers before the crash are

```
j = 1 and arr[j] = 2
i = 5 and arr.size() = 4
```

Comment: `for(int j = i; j<length; j++)
                {
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];` What do you think `j+1` will give you when `j==length-1`?

Comment: sounds like it would access something outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: Yes! You should rethink your loop condition. While you're at it, consider the case where the user wants to erase an element not inside the array. Also consider the case where there may be duplicates in the array.

Comment: I will rethink that for sure, but the issue is that i get this error while in the while loop of the main where no erase() function is called, I wanna make sure this is running before I fix up my logic

Comment: Can you show your `size()` function?

Comment: int& size()
{
return length;
}

Comment: omg you just made me realize I was returning the length and not the capacity haha omg silly mistake thank you @AndyG I finally got it and you have been a huge help

Comment: Great, you worked through it yourself ;-)